# How to access query result with the selection as object name

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have made a query on a data and it returns a result:
`[ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(t.id)': 2 } ]`

How can I access it like the count number?
I have tried `result.COUNT(t.id)` but it isn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the object is named, you need to access it like so:

```
result[0]["COUNT(t.id)"]
```

I would rather name the columns explicitly by using aliases in the query:

```
select count(t.id) as count_of_id
from ...
```

Comment: The first method works well. Thank you. However, it outputs undefined if I rename the name as the second method. (I calling as result[0].count_of_id).

Comment: It should work. Log the result and check, may be there is a typo or upper/lower case issue.